# Linux put permissions good

Tags: linux, permissions

What I would like to is create a directory that belongs to a group and each of those member can create, edit & remove files.

```
chgrp OldGroup NewGroup
chmod g=rwx
```

That's what I learned, but now my big problem is that I need to make sure people from that group can only delete their own files.

I am not sure how to put these rights,
if you have any ideas, please share them!

Thnx for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try setting sticky bit?

```
chmod 1775 /directory/with/group/files
```

when the sticky bit is enabled on a directory, users (other than the owner) can only remove their own files inside a directory. This is used on directories like /tmp whose permissions are 1777=rwxrwxrwt

Comment: I am new to this kind of permissions, I see that you change permissions to 1775 wich I don't understand very well, I only seen 3 numbers till now, u,g,o (like 777). Could it please be possibel to explain it a bit more?

Comment: 1 in front of 775 is sticky bit :) - when you set this it will do exactly what I wrote above